# Add spacing between words

Tags: html, css

I am creating a front-end for google homepage for a project, but I am confused about how to apply spacing of the nav bar same as the original google home page. The code below has spacing something like this:`About  Store  Images  Sign in` but I want something like this `About  Store                                 Images Sign in`.

```css
html{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
            <a href="#" id="store">Store</a>
            <a href="#" id="images">Images</a>
            <a href="#" id="sign-in">Sign in</a>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <img src="google.png" alt="img" width="auto">
            <form action="https://google.com/search">
                <input type="text" name="q">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
                <input type="submit" name="btnI" value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <a href="#" id="advertising">Advertising</a>
            <a href="#" id="business">Business</a>
            <a href="#" id="how_search_works">How Search works</a>
            <a href="#" id="privacy">Privacy</a>
            <a href="#" id="terms">Terms</a>
            <a href="#" id="settings">Settings</a>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

I will appreciate any help or suggestions for this.

Comment: So, you want the menu items to be spaced a `1 2` on the left and `3 4` on the right of the page?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
html{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: black;
} 
#header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div>
                <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
                <a href="#" id="store">Store</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#" id="images">Images</a>
                <a href="#" id="sign-in">Sign in</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <img src="google.png" alt="img" width="auto">
            <form action="https://google.com/search">
                <input type="text" name="q">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
                <input type="submit" name="btnI" value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <a href="#" id="advertising">Advertising</a>
            <a href="#" id="business">Business</a>
            <a href="#" id="how_search_works">How Search works</a>
            <a href="#" id="privacy">Privacy</a>
            <a href="#" id="terms">Terms</a>
            <a href="#" id="settings">Settings</a>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That works out nicely. I really appreciate your help.